# Is the process of volume decrease in NaOH solutions reversible during evaporation of water from the solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, evaporation

While preparing w/w 50% NaOH solution I noticed a decrease in solution volume (5-10mL) in a 2L volumetric flask, so I am wondering if there is an increase in water volume during the water evaporation or concentration of NaOH? Is it the same amount and is it measurable?

[QuantumYitian question regarding the decrease of volume during the dissolution of NaOH](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167434/why-is-there-a-decrease-in-the-total-volume-when-naoh-dissolves-in-water)

Comment: Try to reformulate your question to make more clear, what *exactly* you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no water volume in solution. $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions and $\ce{H2O}$ molecules are packed together in solution in average tighter than is the average packing tightness for $\ce{NaOH(s)}$ and $\ce{H2O(l)}$ alone.

At water evaporation, the mass concentration of $\ce{NaOH}$ obviously increases until solution saturation. After that, extra $\ce{NaOH}$ crystalizes.

If all water evaporates and then condenses, the initial volumes are obtained, if we neglect experimental troubles of removing all water.

---

The difference of volumes during dissolution (assuming the same initial and final temperature) can be determined from experimental or tabulated values of volume, mass or density:

- Measured mass/volume and measured/known density of solute
- Measured volume/mass and measured/known density of solvent
- Measured volume or measured/tabulated density of solution at give concentration

Many solutions, including $\ce{NaOH}$ have [tabulated densities](https://www.handymath.com/cgi-bin/naohtble3.cgi?submit=Entry) that can be interpolated and the volume difference calculated.

Here is the simple formula to calculate the difference:

$$\Delta V = V_\mathrm{solution} - V_\mathrm{solute} - V_\mathrm{solvent} = \\
\frac{m_\mathrm{solute} + m_\mathrm{solvent}}{\rho_\mathrm{solution}} - \frac{m_\mathrm{solute}}{\rho_\mathrm{solute}} - \frac{m_\mathrm{solvent}}{\rho_\mathrm{solvent}}=
\\
\frac{m_{\ce{NaOH}} + m_{\ce{H2O}}}{\rho_\mathrm{solution}} - \frac{m_{\ce{NaOH}}}{\rho_{\ce{NaOH(s)}}} - \frac{m_{\ce{H2O}}}{\rho_{\ce{H2O}}}=
\\
\frac{m_{\ce{NaOH}} + V_{\ce{H2O}}\cdot \rho_{\ce{H2O}}   }{\rho_\mathrm{solution}} - \frac{m_{\ce{NaOH}}}{\rho_{\ce{NaOH(s)}}} - V_{\ce{H2O}}$$

- $V$ is volume
- $\rho$ is density
- $m$ is mass

Comment: How do you obtain the volume of a solute, e.g., NaOH in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I am still thinking. You mean the density of solid NaOH?

Comment: @Achem  Both solid and solution.  V(NaOH(s))=m(NaOH(s)) /rho(NaOH(s)) // You wieght NaOH, obtain its density and calculate its volume.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification.