# Density of dissolved and non-dissolved salts

Tags: physical-chemistry, density

I am doing a calculation, which needs to be 100% correct. My question is as follows; Does the density of dissolved salt differentiate from the density of non-dissolved salts?

My specific problem is a solution of 75% potassium formate in water. When the salt is dissolved, the salt molecule is broken down to K+ and COOH-. This, at least in my mind have to affect the density of the dissolved ions from the density of crystalline salt (non-dissolved). This in turn, would mean that a calculation of the exact density can not be calculated from the density of pure non-dissolved potassium formate (@ 1.91kg/l).

Is there any table I can look up the density of the ions directly, or does anyone have any tips to point me in the right direction? Are this difference negligible? Or are my hypothesis just plain wrong? All answers are appreciated.

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0017931018353067 has the data and fits you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers and the reference. Yeah, I wrote a little quick there, we are using formic acid in the production for the formate :) The 20-degree reference is perfect, specifically, I'm looking for the values at 22C. My wording while looking for an answer may be the reason I was struggling, it's not easy having just a bachelor. Anyways, thanks a lot for the quick reply. Now I know where to ask when I'm stuck

Comment: This is not quite an answer but an edit to the question. I can see you haven't registered to this site. Please register and edit your question. This will merge your account.

Answer (score 4):

Poutnik has nicely explained in his answer what you have to do to get reliable data. Unfortunately, tabulated density data of potassium formate is hard to found. However, I have found two reliable datasets (Ref. 1 & 2) with very agreeable data sets at two extremes (densities of 5-25% solutions in Ref.1 and that of 50-78% solutions in Ref.2, which was mentioned by Jon Custer in his comment):

[image: Density Vs weight% of KCOOH solutions]

Now, since the graph has good agreement of data $(R^2 = 0.9971)$, and using the straightline equation, you can find any density of given solution. Note that the data is for solutions at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$.

**References:**

1. Åke Melinder, Thermophysical Properties of Aqueous Solutions Used as Secondary Working Fluids," *Ph.D. Thesis* **2007**, Royal Institute of Technology, Stockholm, Sweden (ISBN 978-91-7178-707-1).
2. Tao Wen, Meng Wang, Yi Chen, Weifeng He, and Yimo Luo, "Thermal properties study and performance investigation of potassium formate solution in a falling film dehumidifier/regenerator," *International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer* **2019**, *134*, 131-142 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2019.01.031).

Answer (score 2):

Better than "density of dissolved salt" is using the term "density of the salt solution", which if a function of the particular solution concentration.

As there is no law of total volume conservation, the volume of final solution may differ (is usually little smaller for salts) from the sum of volumes of solvent and (bulk) salt to be dissolved.

The density of a particular salt solution cannot be calculated from basic principles. It has to be determined experimentally, or interpolated from already known tabulated solution density data.

For common salts, there are often published tabulated data of solution densities for given mass concentrations or mass percentages.

If no solution density data are available, you can use as a very rough first approximation the calculated density from the total masses and total volumes of the solvent and the (bulk) salt. BUT, it is highly recommended to measure density (or calculate it from the mass and the volume) at least for one or two solutions close to solution concentrations of your interest.

Then, you can use an interpolation function, available in numerical mathematical methods, to interpolate density data.

Look also on the related question  [Why water volume went up by almost the same amount after adding salt?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/170538/35806)

---

There is also no salt molecule $\ce{HCOOK}$. It is just a summary formula, expressing stoichiometric ratio of ions  $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{HCOO-}$  1:1 in a salt crystal or its solution.